# Incorrect output in Immediate Previous Larger Number code

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, optimization

Que: N numbers are passed as input to the program. The program must print the immediate previous larger number. If there is no such larger number print 0 for that specific number.

Note: As N can be as high as 100000, optimize your algorithm to avoid timeout.

Input Format: The first line contains N. The second line contains N numbers separated by a space.

Output Format: The first line contains N numbers which denote the immediate previous larger number.

Boundary Conditions: 2 <= N <= 100000

Example Input/Output 1: Input: 11 455 346 76 304 488 374 385 433 350 9 1000

Output: 0 455 346 346 0 488 488 488 433 350 0

My code is as following :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int n;
 int a[100000],b[100000];
 cin>>n;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     cin>>a[i];
 }

 for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(a[i]>a[i-1])
     {
         b[i]=0;
     }
     else
     {
         b[i]=a[i-1];
     }
 }

 b[0]=0; 

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     cout<<b[i]<<" ";
 }
}
```

Output of my code : 0 455 346  0  0 488  0   0  433 350 0

Expected :          0 455 346 346 0 488 488 488 433 350 0

I'm unable to figure out the problem here and please suggest how to optimize the code.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem (the task you are trying to solve). It is not clear enough...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach -

1. Use a stack which will track the previous larger elements in ascending order.
2. Do left to right scan and for every element `arr[i]`, keep popping from stack until the top element of stack is greater than current number

   i. If the stack is empty, there is no greater number in left than current. print 0

   ii. otherwise print the top element of stack which is the immediate previous greater number.
3. Push the current element into stack.

Code:

```
void immediatePreviousLarger(int arr[], int n) {
    stack<int> Stack;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while(!Stack.empty() and Stack.top() <= arr[i]) {
            Stack.pop();
        }
        if(Stack.empty()) {
            printf("0 ");
        } else {
            printf("%d ", Stack.top());
        }
        Stack.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Time complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: "Use a stack" nope, totally not needed.

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere stack is compulsory. This is one of the approaches which will let his solution get *accepted* and avoid *time limit exceeded*.

Comment: thanks man ! could you suggest me some other way to solve this other than using stack where time complexity remains O(n).

Comment: you're welcome! unfortunately, no! but I think you need some data-structure with LIFO property like stack, otherwise the time complexity will be hard to be kept O(n).